# How to develop a numerical differentiation formula using Taylor expansion/series?

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, numerical-optimization

I have a problem understanding a numerical differentiation problem, using Taylor series.

It's an exercise and we should develop a 2nd order approximation formula, which uses just $f(x), f(x-h)$ and $f(x+3h)$. As help, the professor gave us a tip in the exercice, that we should start with:

$$f'(x) = \frac{af(x+3h) + bf(x) + cf(x-h) }h $$

Attached here is the problem AND the solution (which I think is wrong, or he made something wrong, at least I hope), and a legend for my questions.

[image: exercise]

I found other results, and here are my 3 questions:

1. For point 1 (marked 1 on the screenshot), I found $27/6$ as factor there, not $9/2$
2. My 2. question (marked 2 in screenshot) concerns the last term in the result. Shouldn't we multiply that big term with $h^3$?
3. 3rd question (marked 3 in screenshot): Let's say the professor is right, and there are no typos or calculating errors. If we are dividing by $h$, these $h$'s on the nominator will get eliminated by 1 power. So the term (middle term), that he says should be 1, is multiplied by $h$, and if we divide by $h$ there won't be any $h$ anymore there. For the term after if, which is multiplied by $h^2$, and we are dividing by $h$, it will be then just $h$, which makes our formula of 1st order. Or did I understand something wrong?

Thank you for any help! Exam is tomorrow, and I am really freaking out about this.

Comment: thanks for looking up at the question. I tried as stated above, that I found for point 1 for example, on that point 27/6, and for point 2, I multiply the term there with h^3. He doesn't multiply it with nothing. Where are the h^3?

Comment: 1. $9/2=27/6$ is correct. 2.You forgot the factor $1/h$

Comment: But there is an error in 1: it should read $f'''(x_0)$ not $f'''(0)$.

Comment: you're right for 1, thanks. But for 2, how he forgot 1/h?  I am saying he should multiply there with h^3. If you look at the line before, from which he's derivating that line. He is summing the h's, so a term multiplies h, another h^2, and another term multiplies h^3. Or am I wrong. Still don't get it. Where are the h^3 of line before gone? And where is here getting "-9/2" MINUS not +9/2.

Comment: It should read $\Big(\frac{9}{2} a f'''(x_0)-\frac{1}{6}cf'''(x_0)\Big)h^3$

Comment: exactly! So this professor's correction is wrong there, right? He added a "minus" before "9/2" and forgot the h^3 term as you stated in the comment before.

Answer (score 2):

1) $\frac {27}{6} = \frac 92$

2) yes there should be an $h^3$ factor multiplying that term.  However, that term ultimately gets dropped (actually becomes the error estimate). And is not relevant for finding optimal values of $a, b, c$

3) yes the $h's$ cancel. That is kind of the point.

$\frac 1h [(a+b+c)f(x) + (3a+c)f'(x)h + (\frac 92 a + \frac 12 c) f''(x)h^2+\epsilon h^3] = f'(x)$

Which can only be true if

$(a+b+c) = 0$ and $(3a+c) = 1$

as for $\frac 92 a + \frac 12 c = 0$ This makes your error term decrease at quadratic speed rather than linear speed.

Comment: but how does it drop completely? if there were the h^3 (which he forgot to write on the solution), it will be just h^2 (after dividing by h), and not drop completely.. I dont get it :(

Comment: I thought, it's the most important term! We divide the h^3 by h, so we he h^2, and that's our 2nd order formula, he's looking for

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
suppose you want
to find
$f'(x) \approx \dfrac{af(x+uh) + bf(x+vh) + cf(x+wh) }h
$.

$f(x+rh)
=f(x)+rhf'(x)+r^2h^2f''(x)/2+r^3h^3f'''(x)/6+O(h^4)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
af(x+uh) + bf(x+vh) + cf(x+wh)
&=(a+b+c)f(x)+(au+bv+cw)hf'(x)\\
&\quad +(au^2+bv^2+cw^2)h^2f''(x)/2+(au^3+bv^3+cw^3)h^3f'''(x)/6\\
&\quad+O(h^4)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore you want
$0=a+b+c,
1=au+bv+cw,
0=au^2+bv^2+cw^2
$
and the error is
$(au^3+bv^3+cw^3)h^2f'''(x)/6
+O(h^3)
$.

This leads to Vandermonde determinants.

Your case is
$u=3, v=0, w=-1$,
so
$0=a+b+c,
1=3a-c,
0=9a+c
$.

Adding the second and third,
$a=1/12$,
so
$c = -9a
=-3/4$.

From the first,
$b = -a-c
=-1/12+3/4
=2/3
$.

The error coefficient is
$au^3+bv^3+cw^3
=27/12-3/4
=15/12
=5/4
$
so the error is
$(5/4)h^2f'''(x)/6+O(h^3)
=(5/24)h^2f'''(x)+O(h^3)
$.